# node js express framework video streaming not working for second time

Tags: node.js, express, node.js-stream

Trying to implement the app where user can select and play any video from the list. For the first run it works very smoothly the streaming and all but as soon as I click logout or back and play another video just getting black video player. 
Below is the code to play the video:

```
    app.get('/video', function(req, res) {
  var getVideoID = req.headers["referer"];
  getVideoID = getVideoID.substring(getVideoID.indexOf("=")+1,getVideoID.Length);
  const path = video_path[getVideoID];//'assets/electronic_effects.flv'
  const stat = fs.statSync(path);
  const fileSize = stat.size;
  const range = req.headers.range;

  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
    var end = parts[1]
      ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
      : fileSize-1;

    var chunksize = (end-start)+1;
    var maxChunk = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB at a time
    if (chunksize > maxChunk) {
      end = start + maxChunk - 1;
      chunksize = (end - start) + 1;
    }
    file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end, autoClose: true})
    .on("open", function() {
          file.pipe(res);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('stream end');
    })
    .on('close', function () {
      console.log('stream close');
    });
    const head = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunksize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }

    res.writeHead(206, head);

  } else {
    const head = {
      'Content-Length': fileSize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(200, head)
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
  }
})
```

Black screen of horror on second video access. 
[The black video player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQqpG.png)

I strongly feel like the stream is not getting close. Any help will be appreciated. Using node for the first time here. Pardon for the silly mistakes ;) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like `file` is a global variable (no `var`/`let`). Are you sure about it? This way consecutive requests overwrite the same reference. Could it be the issue?

Comment: made `file` local still no difference.

Comment: any update / solution for this? stuck on it

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?

Comment: Yes. Second time I'm getting range as, ```Start :0 :: end :1048575 :: totalChunks :0   <br />                                                                  
Start :257359872 :: end :258125235 :: totalChunks :1048576 ```

Comment: Has the Diogo Spinola's original code the same issue? https://github.com/daspinola/video-stream-sample

Comment: Yes.. exact same code.